# Convert .otf font into a .gif image of all glyphs

Tags: bash, image, fonts, converters

How can I convert a `.otf` font file into a `.gif` image, where each glyph within the font occupies a single frame in the gif?

I have seen imagemagick used to convert glyphs into pngs,

```
convert -background none -fill black -font font.otf -pointsize 300 label:"Z" z.png
```

Is this extendable for what I am after?

Or do I need to use a different method?

(Also note that the above command doesn't work properly for me, the font I am using, tangwar-annatar, has some glyphs that were cut off by the edges of the png generated by the above command)

I'm on a mac with access to pretty much everything, so would accept any solution in any language as long as it works for me.

Comment: By *"each frame in the GIF"* do you an animated GIF or a montage of all the glyphs?

Comment: @MarkSetchell well, an animated gif, but I don't care about the animation itself. I want to upload all the glyphs as separate costumes to a program called Scratch, and the fastest way to do this is to use a gif with one "costume" per frame

Comment: @minseong what does this even mean? Glyphs are not letters, they're just outlines mapped to (sequences of) unicode codepoints, and not even necessarily directly (ligatures are a thing). If you want a "codepage" sheet then there are a million ways to do that using any programming language that has a font parser written for it, so: pick a language, look up whether it has a font parser, and if so, start programming. Then when you get stuck, that's when Stackoverflow might be able to help, [but not before you start](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MarkSetchell your answer, while it's definitely worth an upvote, doesn't really convert _every_ symbol in the font, just the ones in `[a-zA-Z0-9!;]`. I'd really like something that does _every_ symbol from the font

Comment: Ok, thanks for coming back. I don't know how to enumerate all glyphs in a font, but if you find a way, ping me back and we'll try to work out how to get ImageMagick to show them all - by pumping in UTF codes or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Again**

Ok, I have seen your font and the characters seem to extend beyond the expected sizes. I think all you need to do is use a bigger canvas:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
   for c in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do
      convert xc:none[1000x1000] -background none -fill black -font tengwar.otf -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 "$c" miff:-
   done

   # Do any problematic characters as an afterthought, e.g. semi-colon, and exclamation
   convert xc:none[1000x1000] -background none -fill black -font tengwar.otf -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 ";" miff:-
   convert xc:none[1000x1000] -background none -fill black -font tengwar.otf -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 "!" miff:-

} | convert -dispose background -delay 20 miff:- anim.gif
```

[image]

**Updated Answer**

You may get on better with `-annotate` on a fixed background as below. I have also added how to deal with problematic characters in this example - you can do the same in the other example too:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
   for c in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do
      convert xc:none[350x350] -background none -fill black -font arial -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 "$c" miff:-
   done

   # Do any problematic characters as an afterthought, e.g. semi-colon, and exclamation
   convert xc:none[350x350] -background none -fill black -font arial -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 ";" miff:-
   convert xc:none[350x350] -background none -fill black -font arial -pointsize 300 \
         -gravity center -annotate 0 "!" miff:-

} | convert -dispose background -delay 20 miff:- anim.gif
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for c in {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}; do 
   convert -background none -fill black -font arial -pointsize 300 \
   label:"$c" -gravity center -extent 350x350 miff:-
done | convert -dispose background -delay 80 miff:- anim.gif
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, just make the first line of the script a proper shebang. I have edited the answer. And make the script executable, with `chmod +x myScript` and run it with `./myScript`.

Comment: The bounding box is too small for many of the glyphs, have a look at what this generated [here](http://i.cubeupload.com/eeoZ6p.gif). See how many are cutt off on the sides and top. I sometimes also got an error: `convert: width or height exceeds limit 'E' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3800.` for some characters.

Comment: Ok, changing the `-pointsize` fixed the vertical chop-off, but I still get horizontal cropping, and sometimes those `width or height ...` errors

Comment: Your updated answer still has all the same problems as previously, i.e. cropping of the letters: [cubeupload](http://i.cubeupload.com/dT2x1i.gif)

Comment: Can you share this *"mad"* font please and I'll try some experiments with it for you.

Comment: and [this spec](https://www.elfico.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/tngandoc.pdf) might be useful